# Restore the original array code

Tags: arrays, latex-base

The `array`package redefines `array` in various ways. I was woundering if anyone had made a package containing a localized (prefixed) version of the kernel `array`?

I have a document were we have a simple construction that make use of `array` some of the configurations we use does not work as soon as one load the `array` package (which can be nice for other things), so I wanted to create a copy prefix with say `\my@` such that I could use both. So far unsuccessfull.

Basically the only problem is the restrictions that `array` puts on the format parser, so I would also be enough to locally restore the format parser.

Any ideas?

as for an MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array}
\def\test{cc}
\begin{document} 
\[
  \begin{array}{\test}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

without the `array` package the code compiles just fine

EDIT:

Some more back ground. In a book we have a lot of linear equations and such that traditionally in this field is typeset via `array` in order to line up variables etc. We call this a system. Now instead of having to remember all those differnt `array` preambles we are creating a new environment what can be controlled via a `key-val` interface. This way we can for example make sure that all systems have a different `\arraycolsep` than the rest of the document. We can scale a system etc.

Usually all columns have the same alignment (`r`), but for some systems it is preferable to be able to specify a specific format, or even just specify the number of columns and then the format of just the last column.

As already mentioned, this is *easy* with the kernel `array`, but does not work because of the restrictions when the `array` package is loaded.

For the systems we (currently) do not need any of the extra `array` features.

Hope this clearify things a bit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could keep the array package definition but just pre-expand the preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}


\makeatletter

\let\savearray\@@array
\def\@@array[#1]#2{%
\protected@edef\temp{\noexpand\savearray[#1]{#2}}\temp}
\makeatother

\def\test{cc}

\begin{document} 
\[
  \begin{array}{\test}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

This redefinition doesn't stop the usual array package features so long as any commands placed in `>{...}` are latex-robust so don't fail in the protected edef.

Comment: Nice, that seem to do the trick in small scale.

Answer (score 4):

Use at your own risk

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\makeatletter
\let\array@@array\array
\def\after@array#1#2{\array@@array[#2]{#1}}
\renewcommand{\array}[2][c]{\expandafter\after@array\expandafter{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother

\def\test{cc}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{\test}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: that almost works, but the parser still complains if one use `*{3}{\test}`, would it be enough to restore the argument parser to the original version?

Comment: @daleif I'd say no, if you want to use the extended syntax provided by `array`. I can understand the need to have a one-level expansion; giving an option such as `format=*{3}{\test}` is quite mysterious. Would you like to improve your question adding some details?

Comment: One would never give `format=*{3}[\test}`, at least that is not what is indented, but the overall alignment of the matrix is stored in a macro, so at some point `*{NUM}{\macro}` will be used.

Comment: @daleif Expand `\macro` yourself before passing it to `array`. Or use David's strategy, which is riskier if you don't have full control on what is passed.

Comment: Davids solution seem to work as indented

Answer (score 3):

why can't you use this definition? Maybe I didn't understand your problem ...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{cc}
\begin{document} 
\[
  \begin{array}{C}
    a & b \\ c & d
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: because the entire format for the `array` is build via `key-val` options, most times it is just `*{NUM c}` but it may also be supplied as `format=rrllccrllrc` or other options

Answer (score 1):

I have localised `array` package in `xepersian`. Some pieces of code with explanation:

```
\def\@testpach{\@chclass
 \ifnum \@lastchclass=6 \@ne \@chnum \@ne \else
  \ifnum \@lastchclass=7 5 \else
   \ifnum \@lastchclass=8 \tw@ \else
    \ifnum \@lastchclass=9 \thr@@
   \else \z@
   \ifnum \@lastchclass = 10 \else
   \edef\@nextchar{\expandafter\string\@nextchar}%
   \@chnum
   \if \@nextchar c\z@ \else
   \if \@nextchar و\z@ \else
    \if \@nextchar \if@RTLtab r\else l\fi\@ne \else
    \if \@nextchar \if@RTLtab ر\else چ\fi\@ne \else
     \if \@nextchar \if@RTLtab l\else r\fi\tw@ \else
     \if \@nextchar \if@RTLtab چ\else ر\fi\tw@ \else
   \z@ \@chclass
   \if\@nextchar |\@ne \else
    \if \@nextchar !6 \else
     \if \@nextchar @7 \else
      \if \@nextchar <8 \else
       \if \@nextchar >9 \else
  10
  \@chnum
  \if \@nextchar m\thr@@\else
  \if \@nextchar م\thr@@\else
   \if \@nextchar p4 \else
  \if \@nextchar پ4 \else
    \if \@nextchar b5 \else
    \if \@nextchar ز5 \else
   \z@ \@chclass \z@ \@preamerr \z@ \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi
   \fi \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi  \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi \fi}%
```

This code comes from file `misc-localise-xepersian.def`. It localises position arguments. Persian `و‍` for `c`, `ر‍` for `r`, `چ` for `l`, `م` for `m`, `پ` for `p`, `ز` for `b`.

```
\eqenvironment{آرایه}{array}
```

This is from file `environments-ltx.def`. It makes Persian environment `آرایه` equivalent to `array` environment.

```
\eqenvironment{جدول}{tabular}
```

Similar to above. It makes Persian environment `جدول` equivalent to `tabular` environment.

Comment: Nice, but I think I have misused the localize part. I meant it as a prefix of all of the macros used, in the same manner as many of the internal `memoir` macros are prefixed `\m@m`